# Aws lambda messes up my encoding

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using

https://clifff.com/2015/10/01/2015-failed-experiments-with-aws-lambda/
+
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/build-your-own-ivr-with-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-twilio.html

to create an image resizing service on aws lambda ... I solved the content-type issue the first article was stuck at, but encoding seems like a dead end ... any help would be greatly appreciated!

ruby

```
Base64.decode64("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7")
```

-> working image

```
GIF89a\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\x80\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFF\xFF\xFF!\xF9\u0004\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000,\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0001D\u0000;
```

api gateway with

```
$util.base64Decode("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7")
```

-> broken image

```
GIF89a\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000���!�\u0004\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000,\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0001D\u0000;
```

Comment: Your use pattern is not well suited for the combination of API Gateway and Lambda. API Gateway is exclusively a proxy or JSON/XML REST endpoint. Passing binary payloads through it is a hack. You should rather store your binary data directly to S3 and then trigger the Lambda function via notifications or through the API gateway. Search other questions here to find more about it, it's been answered multiple times.

Comment: I cannot store in s3 since this is supposed to be generated images.

Comment: I understand. You need to store your generated binary content in S3 and return 301 redirect to the S3 object URL. You won't be able to return binary content from Lambda through API Gateway directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah ... looks like it's a know issue https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=668306&#668306

Comment: Hit the same wall today. I hope they implement binary response soon.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is super old thread, but since the issue is still not resolved, and the binary support for API GW is miserably documented, I thought that somebody might find the workaround I found useful:

I believe, that binary data is passed around as UTF-8 strings somewhere inside the API GW. If you only need to return a tracking pixel (and not e.g. generated image), then you can avoid the problem with messed encoding by using an image that does not have problematic bytes in its binary data.

For example, the shortest tracking pixel (26 byte long GIF) has a byte with hexadecimal representation 0xFF in the middle. This will break the API GW. But if you edit this picture in hex editor and replace the byte with 0x00, you'll get something that is still a valid image (and EVEN Microsoft browsers don't complain about it), but can still be processed by API GW.

Just make your "Body Mapping" template look like this:

```
$util.base64Decode("R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=")
```